# MVC4 WebGrid Headers Fixed on top

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-table

I am trying to fix the headers of my webgrids on top. So when you scroll, the headers remain in place.

I've tried CSS. And Javascript, with no success.

And most solutions require a known width for each column.. Its a webgrid, there is no fixed width per column..

Does anyone know the proper way to do this?

Alot/All of the solutions, the headers aren't even in line with the table..

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#GridHeader").html("<table>" + $('#gridContent table thead').html() + "</table>");
            $("#GridHeader table tr:first").append("<th style='width:12px;' ></th>");
            $("#GridBody").html("<table>" + $('#gridContent table tbody').html() + "</table>");
            $("#GridFooter").html("<table>" + $('#gridContent table tfoot').html() + "</table>");
            $("#gridContent").hide();
        });
```

```
<style type="text/css">
.colWidth { width: 200px;  }
#GridBody{width: 100% ;height:200px; overflow: auto;  }
#GridHeader table {width: 100%;  margin-top: 0px; padding:0px; border-collapse:collapse; } 
#GridFooter  {width: 100% ; }
#GridHeader table th { width: 10%; border: 2px solid black;}
.title td, .title th { width: 10%;  border: 2px solid black;}
#GridBody td { width: 10%;  border: 2px solid black;} 
</style>

<div id="Outer" >
<div id="GridHeader" class="title"></div>
<div id="GridBody"></div>
<div id="GridFooter"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to use jquery clone method to copy headers

Comment: Why would I want to copy headers? @AndreiMikhalevich

Comment: try `position:fixed;`

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui I get terrible results with it. Headers dont link table, and just shrink width wise.. Not in line with column widths either.

Comment: I know one solution, set the width of each header through jQuery. set width of it according to its coressponding column. :) it's easy! isn't it?

Comment: You'd think so. But out of the last 10 Jquery table plugins ive downloaded ALL, require Width in pixels. None accept %s. The best solution I can come up with, losing the ability to sort the tables.. Why should you have to set both to line up the tables, its a table... stupid plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clone full grid with jquery, then remove tbody from clonned element and fix remaining part on top of the page. This is how I would do this